# How does pytest find files to test?

Tags: python, pytest

I know how py.test discovers tests to run, but I don't know how to make the tests refer to the files that contains the code to test.

My project looks like this:

```
arith.py
tests/
    test_airth.py
```

In my project root directory, I have the file `arith.py` with

```
def plus(x, y):
    return x + y
```

In the file `tests/test_arith.py` I have

```
import arith
def test_plus():
    assert arith.plus(3, 5) == 8
```

When I run, in the project root directory,

```
pytest
```

It discovers my test file, because I followed the test discovery rules. But pytest replies with

> ImportError while importing test module tests/test_arith.py'

I ran `pytest` from the project root, so why does it not like my import? It wants to find the files that I am testing in the `tests` directory!

How can I set up the imports properly, so that my test files in the `tests/` directory, can see the files under test which are in the project root directory? (The examples in pytest's documentation seem to not do anything special...perhaps the tests are in the same directory as the files under test? They describe test discovery in great detail, but I must have missed how to set up the tests so they can see the code they are testing.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have a layout like this (which is what I do):

```
.
├── myprogram
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── core.py
│   └── db.py
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── test_core.py
    └── test_db.py
```

You should be invoking pytest like so:

```
py.test tests
```

I'm fairly sure that's an absolute/relative path to the tests directory. This also assumes that you have done something like `python -m pip install -e .` in your root directory. And you have a `.git` or `.hg` folder there, too :)

> It's a little strange so much is needed. Surely there is a better way?

Actually that *is* the best way. I don't think it's controversial to declare that the best way to distribute your Python application is as a Python package, preferably a [wheel](http://pythonwheels.com/). To do that, you're probably going to need a `setup.py`.

By installing your package (preferably in a venv/virtualenv sandbox) you're ensuring that you know what packages are required to install/run *yours*. If your package is installed that means that any script that does `import myprogram` (using my example layout) will be able to import your package. Which is what you'll be doing in your test suite.

Then your test discovery is as simple as telling pytest where to find it.

Comment: Nice. Interestingly, what I am trying to distribute is a single file, which clients use by saying simply `import thething`. I've built large multi-file apps in which `pytest` a part, and yes the tests directory was a sibling of `main`, `models`, `views` and of course `env`. When packaged this way, clients would say `from models import whatever` or `import models`.  To get what I want I guess I have to not just have `thething.py` and instead make `thething/` a sibling of `tests` and put all my code in `thething/__init__.py`. It's only a couple hundred lines...

Comment: If you're trying to provide something that you want people to import then you *definitely* want to create a package - even if it's just a single file. You can still do that with `setup.py`. And if you take that approach you can have `thething.py` and `tests/` in the same folder.

Comment: how to list directories that pytests visits in search of tests?